# Can not implicitly convert type IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I am trying to retrieve some records from the database based on an ID parameter that comes in. How ever it gives me an error saying

> Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable
>   SourceModel to SourceModel.An explicit conversion exists(are you
>   missing a cast)

This is the part of the query to connect to the db

```
public static class Source
{
    public static IEnumerable<SourceModel> GetRecords(string ID, Func<SourceModel,bool> criteria = null)
    {
        var command = new StringBuilder();
        command.AppendFormat("Select * from [RecordsTable] where ID={0}", ID);

        return ExecuteQuery(command.ToString());
    }
}
```

This is the code I tried to pass as follows

```
public static SourceModel GetRecord(string ID)
{
    var recs = Source.GetRecords(ID);
    return  recs; // on this line when i am trying to return the records i get the above mentioned error
}
```

Comment: Hello. Can you provide a [MCVE] and indent your code?

Comment: Alternativly return a specific element without that collection, e.g. `recs.First()`.

Comment: `recs` in your second method will be `IEnumerable<SourceModel>`. You can not return that, since you are specifying that the method returns a single `SourceModel`. So either change the return object to `IEnumerable<SourceModel>` or return a specific `SourceModel` of `recs`

Comment: Is it correct that there are multiple elements with the same ID?

Comment: Note that in order to be protected from SQL injection, you need to pass the query with `{X}` placeholders and the parameter values directly to [`ExecuteQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.datacontext.executequery?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_Linq_DataContext_ExecuteQuery__1_System_String_System_Object___). Your approach with the `StringBuilder` is just as vulnerable as [direct string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683).

Comment: Not related to your error, but you should **NEVER** use string methods (like `StringBuilder.AppendFormat()`) to insert query parameters into SQL statements, this will open you up to [SQL Injection Attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). Use this instead: `string command = "Select * from [RecordsTable] where ID={0}"; return ExecuteQuery<SourceModel>(command, ID);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is due to the `return type` of your method. Change it to return `IEnumerable<SourceModel>` as you are getting `IEnumerable<SourceModel>` from **database**

```
 public static IEnumerable<SourceModel> GetRecord(string ID)
 {
     var recs = Source.GetRecords(ID);
     return  recs; // no error now as you are returning list
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `GetRecords` method returns an `IEnumerable` of `SourceModel`, containing 0 or more items. The `GetRecord` method returns a single `SourceModel`. So you need to convert the "0 or more" to a single result:

```
public static SourceModel GetRecord(string ID)
{
    var recs = Source.GetRecords(ID);
    return recs.FirstOrDefault(); 
}
```